# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Java for one of my classes. The program takes an int from the command line and creates a JButton 2D array of that size. It also has an undo and a new game button. The program compiles and runs and when I click the new game button no exception occurs, but when I click on one of the game spaces, it throws this exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at GameTester.newMove(GameTester.java:28)
    at TicTacToe$GameListener.actionPerformed(TicTacToe.java:145)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

My newMove method simply takes the x and y locations of the button and the turn (1 or 2), and adds it to the 2D int array associated with the GameTester class.

```
public void newMove(int x, int y, int turn)
    {
    board[x][y] = turn;
}
```

This is part of the loop within my ActionListener that includes where the newMove method is called.

```
 if (event == buttons[x][y])
{
    theBoard.moveLog(x,y);
    theBoard.newMove(x,y,toggle);
    if (toggle == 1)
    {
        buttons[x][y].setText("X");
        toggle = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        buttons[x][y].setText("O");
        toggle = 1;
    }
            ..... 
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You probably did not initialize `board` correctly.  Please show us the code where it is initialized.

Comment: public class GameTester
{
 private int[][] board;
 private int lastX;
 private int lastY;
 private int size;
 
 public GameTester(int x)
 { 
  //initialize all to 0
  size = x;
  board = new int[size][size];
  for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
  {
   for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
   {
    board[y][z] = 0;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: x is the size of the game board that is entered from the command line.

Comment: @user2984357 ensure that (0 <= x <= size) and (0 <= y <= size) in the `newMove` method. It seems like your array size is 0 or 1 but x or y is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have provided the problem is likely that `buttons` and `board` are not arrays of the same dimensions. Try using variables to set both sizes or use one to set the other to be sure they are the same size.

## Option 1

```
int X = 3, Y = 3;

JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[X][Y];
char[][] board = new char[X][Y];
```

## Option 2

```
int X = 3, Y = 3;

JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[X][Y];
char[][] board = new char[buttons.length][buttons[0].length];
```

If this isn't the case then you'll need to provide a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) of your problem so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You're right. My code had gotten a little mixed up and I was trying to assign a number an uninitialized array. Thank you so much!